# Access animation defined in xml StateListDrawable

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I have a statelistdrawable for my button like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:drawable="@drawable/spinner"
            android:duration="1200"
            android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
    </item>

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="90"
            android:toDegrees="90"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:drawable="@drawable/spinner"
            android:duration="1200"
            android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Now my button, which is declared in xml, has this file set as its drawableTop.

Normally i would declare the rotate part in res/anim and I can start the animation with

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.spinner);
view.startAnimation(a);
```

But how can I access the Animation if it's inside a state list drawable to make it start? I've tried something like this but now I'm stuck:

```
StateListDrawable background = (StateListDrawable) mRecommendButton.getBackground();
        Drawable drawable = background.getCurrent();
```

Which gives me a drawable but not an Animation.

** EDIT **

apparently it returns a RotateDrawable so I chanched my code but it's still not rotating. Im also using getCompoundDrawables() because I'm setting my drawable xml to Top. Just for the record. It does enter the "if statement".

```
StateListDrawable background = (StateListDrawable) mRecommendButton.getCompoundDrawables()[1];
    Drawable drawable = background.getCurrent();
    if (drawable instanceof RotateDrawable) {
        ((RotateDrawable) drawable).setLevel(500);
    }
```

Comment: rotate tag defines RotateDrawable,  not any Animation

Comment: Thanks. So do I start it with setLevel? Because it's not rotating

Comment: try background.setLevel

Comment: No still not working. But I did found another way to get the RotateDrawable. Edited my question but theres nothing like start() for a RotateDrawable?

Comment: because RotateDrawable is a Drawable,  it just rotates the child Drawable by some angle,  it does not animate it in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Im using a animated-rotate now

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                         android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_black_48"
                         android:pivotX="50%"
                         android:pivotY="50%"
                         android:fromDegrees="0"
                         android:toDegrees="1080"
                         android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
                         android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
```

Java:

```
mRecommendButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.recommended_button);
        StateListDrawable background = (StateListDrawable) mRecommendButton.getCompoundDrawables()[1]; // Drawable set as drawableTop in xml
        Drawable drawable = background.getCurrent();
        if (drawable instanceof Animatable) {
            ((Animatable) drawable).start();
        }
```